# Find unknown broadcast frequency

Tags: frequency-spectrum, frequency, sampling

I'm very new to this stuff, so please excuse the dumb sounding terminology.

I'm trying to capture the data from my elster smart hydro meter. How can I find its frequency (I know its between 902 and 928 MHz and I think there is frequency hopping)?  I have an rtlsdr dongle (2 MHz sample rate) and gnuradio and a raspberrypi.

One idea I had was to listen for an hour on bands:

```
Listen on 902 for an hour
Listen on 904 for an hour 
...
Listen on 928 for an hour
```

Then, I would have to record only when a "blip" in frequency or amplitude happens.  This way, I would have a few blips and I could then try to analyze them.

Does this sound sensible?

Perhaps there is a device that helps with this?

Comment: How many bands you have? How much is the dwell time on band? Is the meaning of 2 MHz sample that you could switch from frequency to other in this rate? Specifying better the signal could allow you to have a better "design" of the scan. I have seen the number 0,5 second for a certain meter - more than enough for a smart single scan.

Comment: Did you do a google search for the meter or look at whats written on the meter? A quick search gives [this link](https://github.com/argilo/gr-elster).

Comment: i just did a search and found this: https://industrycanada.co/number.php?ic=4557A-REXU&id=161862 - so again it just seems like the possible range is 902 to 928, no?

Comment: i'm not sure what you mean by bands. the way I see it (in my very limited knowledge) is that my rtlsdr has a sample rate of about 2 MHz, this means I can break up 928-902=26 so 26/2 = 13, so there are 13 "bands" of 2 MHz, correct??